¿Por qué el if no comprueba si el archivo está vacio en batch?
Estoy haciendo una herramienta que modifique el %PATH% deacuerdo a que lenguaje quiero trabajar en python, pero me encuentro con el problema de que python no puede modificar el %PATH% de la consola, así que uso un script batch que lee un archivo, y modifique el path:
@ECHO OFF
set DIR_BASE=%~dp0
set OUT="%DIR_BASE%out.tmp"

addPath.py %* --OUT %OUT%

if EXIST "%OUT%" (
  set out_path=
  set /p out_path=<%OUT%
  echo "%out_path%"
  IF "%out_path%"=="" (goto del)
  set PATH=%PATH%;%out_path%
  :del
  DEL %OUT% /Q
)
:end
:: https://github.com/dabl03/add-path/blob/main/addPath.bat
@ECHO ON


El problema que encuentro es que al llegar a "set PATH=%PATH%;%out_path%" me corrompe el path, dando como valor: \out.tmp"" (;c:\ruta\mysql\bin. No encuentro el error, y lo peor es que cuando no hay salida (el archivo out.tmp está vacío) el %PATH% vale:  \out.tmp"" (;.

Nota: No tengo problema con el archivo python, de hecho me genera la salida como debe:

out.tmp:
c:\ruta\mysql\bin


Cuando probé su pregunta, descrubí que habían cáracteres en el PATH que echaron un error (no sé cuales son).  Tal vez puede ser un parte de su problema?

@Duston Si. En mi caso el path agarra el valor de out.tmp"" (;

Para evitar que los espacios den errores debes usar comillas a la hora de definir las variables. Por ejemplo:
set "PATH=%PATH%;%out_path%"

